# ProgressBar blocked while MediaPlayer is playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-progressbar

I'm trying to make a circular progress of the MediaPlayer, so it's **indeterminate** while it's preparing and setting progress while it's playing.

I've tried a lot of ways, but this is my last one: I update the bar on a `AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>`.

The class I'm using is [`CircularProgressView`](https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView) but I've tried to swap to `ProgressBar` and the behavior is the **same**:

```
public void startPlaying(final Audio audio, final CircularProgressView progress_view) {

    if (!isPLAYING) {
        progress_view.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress_view.startAnimation();
        isPLAYING = true;
        audioPlaying = audio;
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                    publishProgress((int)-1);

                    mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mp.getDuration();
                    mp.start();

                    while (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        publishProgress((int) (mp.getCurrentPosition()));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(audio.getFile().getUrl());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        stopPlaying();
                        publishProgress((int)-2);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                int value = (int)values[0];
                if (value == -1) {
                    progress_view.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progress_view.setMaxProgress(mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds);
                } else if (value == -2) {
                    progress_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    progress_view.setProgress((int) values[0]);
                    System.out.println("setting: " + values[0]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                super.onPostExecute(o);
            }
        }.execute();

    } else {
        isPLAYING = false;
        stopPlaying();
    }
}
```

on debug, the `ProgressBar` or `CircularProgressView` `.setProgress()` is called during the audio reproduction, but it remains blocked in `indeterminate`, but `progress_view.setIndeterminate(false)` is called as well, and it doesn't become indeterminate.

When the audio finishes, the `ProgressBar` or `CircularProgressView` gets 100% progress.

Any clue?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

EDIT:

as @Blackbelt suggested, I had to call `mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mp.getDuration();` before `publishProgress((int)-1);`

but now this is the behavior:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-V0KHNRjbE_b3hkbkwtTXhIeTg/view?usp=sharing

---

**EDIT 2**: Log of `mp.getDuration()` and `mp.getCurrentPosition()`:

http://pastebin.com/g93V5X9F

or maybe this is more clear:

http://pastebin.com/kYm01Gpg

called on this part:

```
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                int value = (int)values[0];
                if (value == -1) {
                    progress_view.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progress_view.setMaxProgress(mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds);
                    Log.i("Stackoverflow:", "setMaxProgress to " + mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds);
                } else if (value == -2) {
                    progress_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    progress_view.setProgress((int) values[0]);
                    Log.i("Stackoverflow:", "setProgress to " + (int)values[0]);

                }
            }
```

---

**EDIT 3**: I'm adding the new code, commenting out the functions `setIndeterminate(boolean)` and swapping into `ProgressBar`:

**XML:**

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progress="40"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play_button" />
```

**Java**:

```
public void startPlaying(final Audio audio, final ProgressBar progress_view) {

    if (!isPLAYING) {
        Log.i("Stackoverflow", "startPlaying called");
        audio.put("times_listened", audio.getTimes_Listened() + 1);
        audio.saveEventually();

        progress_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isPLAYING = true;
        audioPlaying = audio;
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                    mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mp.getDuration();
                    publishProgress((int)-1);


                    mp.start();

                    while (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        publishProgress((int) (mp.getCurrentPosition()));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(audio.getFile().getUrl());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        stopPlaying();
                        publishProgress((int)-2);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                int value = (int)values[0];
                if (value == -1) {
                    progress_view.setMax(mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds);
                    Log.i("Stackoverflow:", "setMaxProgress to " + mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds);
                } else if (value == -2) {
                    progress_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    progress_view.setProgress((int) values[0]);
                    Log.i("Stackoverflow:", "setProgress to " + (int)values[0]);

                    System.out.println("setting: " + values[0]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                super.onPostExecute(o);
            }
        }.execute();

    } else {
        isPLAYING = false;
        stopPlaying();
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 4**:

I'm calling `progress_view.isDeterminate()` and it's returning me `true` everytime. So I decided to do when modifying the progress:

```
 @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                int value = (int)values[0];
                if (value == -1) {
                    progress_view.setMax(mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds);
                    Log.i("Stackoverflow:", "setMaxProgress to " + mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds);
                } else if (value == -2) {
                    progress_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    if (progress_view.isIndeterminate()) // LOOK AT THIS
                        progress_view.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progress_view.setProgress((int) values[0]);
                    Log.i("Stackoverflow:", "setProgress to " + (int) values[0]);
                    Log.i("Stackoverflow", "Indeterminate state: " + progress_view.isIndeterminate());

                    System.out.println("setting: " + values[0]);
                }
            }
```

and the output is always:

> Indeterminate state: true

*WHY ? * :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to call `mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mp.getDuration();` before calling `publishProgress((int)-1);` and not after, or not using that member at all, since you keep already the `MediaPlayer` as member, you could query directly it.

**Edit**

To fix the problem in your video, you have to use the following style `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal`. With the circular `ProgressBar`, the `setIndetermiate` flag is ignored

Comment: Hi, the behavior changed, but still doesn't work, this is how it works:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-V0KHNRjbE_b3hkbkwtTXhIeTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: why do you have `setOnCompletionListener` in onPreExecute ?

Comment: where should I set it ? it's like setting something to make it work at the end

Comment: my bad, I did read `setOnPreparedListener`. Can you log the values of getDuration and getCurrentPosition ?

Comment: I'm going to add a second one, just to see that `setMaxProgress` is called before.

Comment: is it possible that you are calling `startPlaying` more than once ?

Comment: if you think the question is good could you give me +1 to make it more visible to others?

Comment: did you try with the progressbar provided by android ? Just to see if it's a bug of the library

Comment: yes, as I mentioned in the question. I've tried with `CircularProgressView` and `ProgressBar` . The only difference is the funcion `setMaxProgress(float)` for `CircularProgressView` and `setMax(int)` for `ProgressBar`... and the `startAnimation()` on `CircularProgressView` starts the indeterminate animation of circling.

Comment: I think I'll start a bounty tomorrow.

Comment: did you try with `ProgressBar` also after the `mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds` change ?

Comment: This is a nightmare... well I've tried to put it as `ProgressBar` and `android:indeterminate="false"` and it shows indeterminate = true... I commented out all the lines which calls `progress_view.setIndeterminate(boolean)`......

Comment: how about you do a gist wit the code, just to have a clear picture

Comment: There's a problem that I discovered, I'm editing again

Comment: from the documentation of setIndeterminate: *If this progress bar's style only supports indeterminate mode (such as the circular progress bars), then this will be ignored.* Could it be your case?

Comment: That's the tweak !! setting `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal` does the project (but it's horizontal...) do you know what's the style for circular with progress?

Comment: there is no such style. You have to write your own

Comment: Ok, if you modify the answer I'll mark it as valid because you basically solved my problem.